# how to insert using join in query

Tags: sql

i have a table like this

```
registrationId | standardId | courseId | marks
===============================================
5001           |     1      |    1     |   67
5001           |     1      |    2     |    87
```

and so on my question is the standard name and course name come from different tables so while updating i have to use 3 diffent queries 1st to get standardId according to standard name courseid acording to coursename and later update into this table. can it be done in one query?

Comment: Please share standard table and course table too

Comment: Make it easy to help you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Punctuation exists for a reason; you should use it. Without it, such a long sentence is difficult to read and understand.

Title says "insert", body says "update"; which one is it?

For `UPDATE`, something like this might do what you need:

```
update this_table tt set
  tt.standardid = (select s.standardid 
                   from standard s
                   where s.standard_name = :some_unique_standard_name
                  ),
  tt.courseid   = (select c.courseid
                   from course c
                   where c.course_name = :some_unique_course_name
                  )
where tt.registrationid = :some_registration_id;
```

For `INSERT`:

```
insert into this_table 
  (registrationid, standardid, courseid, marks)
select 
  :some_registration_id,
  (select s.standardid 
   from standard s
   where s.standard_name = :some_unique_standard_name
  ), 
  (select c.courseid
   from course c
   where c.course_name = :some_unique_course_name
  ),
  :marks_value
from dual;
```

- in both cases, subqueries **must** return a single value
- colon (`:`) represents a *variable* whose value you need to provide
- syntax is based on Oracle; your database might differ (especially for `INSERT`, as there's probably no `DUAL` table elsewhere).